# CSS - Width of a child percent of another child (like table)

Tags: css, angularjs

Is there any way that I can create a table width divs instead, so that I can create the "row's td width" be the same as the header? Like the `<td>` in the `<tbody>` that is the same width as the `<th>` from `<thead>`?

The reason why I am doing this is because I need a table, and I want to use [Angular UI Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) and this only works with `<ul>` or `<div>` and not tables.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to apply custom CSS for each type of divs

```
.table {}
.tbody {}
.tr {}
.td {}
```

create your HTML like this

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td"></div>
    <div class="td"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for `th` tags you might want to add additional class to that, like

```
<div class="th td"></div>
```

Comment: I understand that. I meant you know how in a table if you set the `<th>` width, then the `<td>` corresponding to the `<th>` will automatically also have the same width. How can I accomplish that? Or do I need to manually do that?

Comment: You can add another class and for `th`, you will need to assign two classes to that div. Like `<div class="th td">`. Hope, it solves your problem

Comment: Oh perfect. Thanks! Actually, but in a real application, each `<td>` is a different width. So that means for each `<td>` I need to create a unique identifier

Comment: Also just to add you can use the css styles for display like display:table; or display:table-cell; etc. to get the table style layout on other elements.